# Firebase Analytics Logs not showing custom events

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase is not showing my custom events in logs, but automatic events are there.

[image]

```java
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("type","event" );
bundle.putString("event_Page", "hamburger");
bundle.putString("event_key", "about_us");
bundle.putString("action_type", "click");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("testing", bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the timeframe displayed in your dashboard to "Today". If "weekly"/... is selected, it will not display events logged today.

Comment: It's weird that automatic events are displayed though